# Reading cell value with applied number format?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Using `openpyxl` I've been able to get all the code in place to read .xlsx tables to generate .xml needed for a specific technical document tool. I'm trying to make the code general to work for just about any table someone on my team may generate and one issue that has bitten me is that some columns in the XML have formatting applied to save some typing.

For example, I have a table with a column for the line ID and the text, in Excel, reads as Test-001, Test-002, Test-003, etc. To save typing, I've set up a custom number format in Excel as "Test-"000, allowing someone to type  any of the column's cells and have it convert to the Test-. The value returned when reading the cell value with `openpyxl` returning .

Short of checking the number_format on every column and using a regular expression to extract the string and add it to the read value, is there a trivial way with `openpyxl` (2.2.6) to have the the value return what is seen by the Excel user?

That would greatly generalize my code, as some tables might not have the ID column.

Here is a minimum working example of the python:

```
import openpyxl
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('Reading from ExampleWrkBook.xlsx')
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ExampleWrkBook.xlsx')
    wrkSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    logging.info('The first ID value in the sheet is "TestID-001", but openpyxl returns {0:s}'.format(str(wrkSheet['B3'].value)))
```

And an example spreadsheet can be found on DropBox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10370671/ExampleWrkBook.xlsx).

Comment: Without a file it's quite difficult to understand exactly what you mean. It's worth noting, however, that custom number formats that use placeholders get converted by Excel into strings.

Comment: I've edited the entry to now include sample code and a link to example spreadsheet.

Comment: So you want to convert integers to formatted strings using the custom number format? This is all that Excel is doing. No need for a regular expression at all. But you will need to check every cell for the custom format.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid having to check every cell for the number format, but it's not that hard.