# Reading cell value with applied number format openpyxl? - redux

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Python 2.7, openpyxl 2.4.x

I'm trying to read a cell that is a date value ("05/01/2016") in excel and has custom number formatting applied ("yyyymm") so it displays as "201605". What I want to end up with is the value after the custom number formatting is applied (i.e. what the user sees in excel ("201605")). Any idea how to do this using openpyxl?

Note: I can't just simply take the date and reformat it to yyyymm as the user might change the custom formatting and I need whatever the end result is after the custom format is applied. So maybe there's a way in openpyxl to apply the custom formatting in cells that are read?

I realize this is very similar to this post ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675739/reading-cell-value-with-applied-number-format?newreg=805f7ed6aeeb40a7bb395f5da964fe27)) but I wasn't quite sure how to apply it in my circumstance

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I see a couple of downvotes but no comment as to why. Please let me know so I can correct whatever caused it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented.
What you are looking for is cell.number_format.
Try the following:

```
def pyDateFormat(nf):
  import re
  """Convert xlsx cell.number_format to Python date Format."""
  #xlsx Format   = 'YYYYMMDD', 'YYYY\\-MM\\-DD'
  #Python Format = '%Y%m%d'
  nf = re.sub(r'\\',r'',nf,0,re.IGNORECASE) #Remove Escapes
  nf = re.sub(r'([^Y]*)(Y+)(.*)',r'\1%Y\3',nf,0,re.IGNORECASE) #Change YYYY to %Y
  nf = re.sub(r'([^M]*)(M+)(.*)',r'\1%m\3',nf,0,re.IGNORECASE) #Change MM to %m
  nf = re.sub(r'([^D]*)(D+)(.*)',r'\1%d\3',nf,0,re.IGNORECASE) #Change DD to %d
  return nf
#end def pyDateFormat
```

At the point you need the formated cell.value do:

```
  cell = wb.ws['A1']
  if cell.is_date:
    value = cell.value.date().__format__( pyDateFormat(cell.number_format) )
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***