# Date format issue when i web-scraping into excel?

Tags: python, excel, csv, date, web-scraping

I am web-scraping datas from a website with python 2.7, and after i export them to excel.
But i get a format issue in excel :
In the website there is : "9/18" and i get "18.sept" in excel.

How can i hold these values in "9/18" format?

Here my code:

```js
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = open('0910000511.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

datatable=[]
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" )[:-1]:
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
        datatable.append(temp_data)


tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
datatable2=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data2 = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data2.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data2)

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Comment: This is a formatting issue, [edit] your Question to show how you write Excel.

Comment: Im using only "import unicodecsv as csv", so this is the problem?
How can i use this xlsx package correctly?

Comment: It would help to have a copy of your text file, or the URL of where you generated it from.

Comment: I know how i can change date format in Excel. I just asked it, is it possible for holding these values in this format, and not to do manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:
>   I just asked it, is it possible for holding these values in this format, and not to do manually.

There is **NO** hold because a *String* has no Format assigned.

Consider your Dataflow:

```
scrap `Date string` 
-> csv.write `Date string` 
-> Excel imports from CSV `Date string`
```

**Excel Magic** detect `Date string` and convert it to Type **DATE**.
Excel Displays all Cells of Type **DATE** with the Default 
Date Format, resulting in **DAY.SHORTMONTHNAME**.

You have 2 Options:

1. Change the `Date Format` in Excel
   You can do this manually or using a VBA Script.
2. Write your scraped Data using a `xslx package` and assing your
   Date Format("9/18") to the `Date Cells`.
   **Note**: This SO Answer doesn't show how to do `NumberFormat`.
   [SO Answer Solution using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596222/7414759).
   [SO Answer cell.number_format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024394/7414759)
   [openpyxl - A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html)